# Changing Clipboard from outside after setting it in JAVA

Tags: java, clipboard

I am using SystemClipboard to read and write into Clipboard. The Problem is, i want to write into the SystemClipboard (which works perfectly) but later want to be able to see what a person coppied

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
    StringSelection s = null;
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(
             (s = new StringSelection("test")), s
        );

    Clipboard systemClipboard;
    systemClipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard(); 
    Transferable transferData = systemClipboard.getContents( null ); 
    for(DataFlavor dataFlavor : transferData.getTransferDataFlavors()){ 
        Object content;
        try {
            content = transferData.getTransferData( dataFlavor );
            if ( content instanceof String ) { 
                System.out.println((String)content);
            } else {
                System.out.println(content+ "?");
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException e) {} 
    }

    Thread.sleep(5000);
    systemClipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard(); 
    transferData = systemClipboard.getContents( null ); 
    for(DataFlavor dataFlavor : transferData.getTransferDataFlavors()){ 
        Object content;
        try {
            content = transferData.getTransferData( dataFlavor );
            if ( content instanceof String ) { 
                System.out.println((String)content);
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException e) {} 
    }
}
```

If i copy something by using CMD+C / Strg+C in that 5 seconds break, it will still show the text in the console, that i have put into the Clipboard using Java. If i paste by Strg+v / CMD+V it will of course paste the new copied Clipboard. Only Java doesnt recognize it.

What can i do?

Comment: I'm not a Java clipboard expert, but I can tell you that there is a delay when using the Windows clipboard between the time a copy event happens and the time when processes get notified of this change.

Comment: Try removing `if ( content instanceof String ) { System.out.println((String)content); }` from you second check and simply use `System.out.println(content);`

Comment: MadProgrammer, it soll don't work and gave me an Exception: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.io.StringReader cannot be cast to java.lang.String
 at names.ClipboardHandler.main(ClipboardHandler.java:55)

Comment: It's working fine for me... I copied `ta.getTr` in those 5 seconds and this is the program output i got... `test
java.io.StringReader@3b9a45b3?
ta.getTr
ta.getTr
`

Comment: @Codebender which OS, Version, IDE etc. did you use?

Comment: @emmweh, Win 7x64. Jre 1.8.0_45.. Eclipse... And i copied the text from eclipse and chrome browser... Both worked fine...

Comment: @all I found the problem. This only appeared on Linux and Mac OS X. On Windows everything runs smoothly. Due to the fact that i need it to run on a Windows System it is solved for me but maybe someone knows how to make that run on Linux/OS too? How can i make this information available on the top post?